# select multiple objects from list based on values from another list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two lists. One list is of type Cascade (named, cascadeList) & the other list if of type PriceDetails (named priceList), both classes are shown below. I have also given a simple example of what I'm trying to achieve below the classes.

So the priceList contains a list of PriceDetail objects where they can be multiple (up to three) PriceDetail objects with the same ISIN. When there are multiple PriceDetails with the same ISIN I want to select just one based on the Source field.

This is where the cascadeList comes in. So if there were 3 PriceDetails with the same ISIN I would want to select the one where the source has the highest rank in the cascade list (1 is the highest). Hopefully the example below helps.

**Reason for the question**

I do have some code that is doing this for me however its not very efficient due to my lack of skill.

In a nutshell it first creates a unique list of ISIN's from the priceList. It then loops through this list for each unique ISIN to get a list of the PriceDetails with the same ISIN then uses some if statements to determine which object I want. So hoping and pretty sure there is a better way to do this.

**My Classes**

```
class Cascade
{
     int Rank;
     string Source;
}


class PriceDetails
{
     string ISIN;
     string Sedol;
     double Price;
     string Source;
}
```

**Example**

```
PriceList                                Cascade
ISIN   Source    Price                   Source    Rank
BN1    XYZ       100                     ABC       1
MGH    PLJ       102                     XYZ       2
BN1    PLJ       99.5                    PLJ       3
BN1    ABC       98
MGH    XYZ       102
```

**Result I'm looking for**

```
PriceList
ISIN   Source   Price
BN1    ABC      98
MGH    XYZ      102
```

Comment: If highest rank is the criteria why `XYZ` is there in the result and that too why with price 102?

Comment: you're correct the source doesn't need to be there - was just trying to make it clear. The price MGH with source XYZ is 102 as the only other MGH object has a source PLJ but that is lower than XYZ in the cascade - hope that makes sense

Comment: @mHelpMe can u paste a code u use for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For getting the desired result we must do these steps:

1. Join two lists based on `Source` property.
2. Group the last result by `ISIN` property.
3. After grouping we must get the minimum rank for
   each `ISIN`.
4. Then we will use the `minRank` variable to compare it
   against the rank of an elements with the same `ISIN` and then select
   the first element.

We can write this query either with [**query** or **method** syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb397947.aspx).

With query syntax:

```
var result = from pr in pricesList
             join cas in cascadesList on pr.Source equals cas.Source
             select new { pr, cas } into s
             group s by new { s.pr.ISIN } into prcd
                let minRank = prcd.Min(x => x.cas.Rank)
             select prcd.First(y => y.cas.Rank == minRank).pr;
```

With method syntax:

```
var result = pricesList.Join(cascadesList,
                  pr => pr.Source,
                  cas => cas.Source,
                  (pr, cas) => new { pr, cas })
            .GroupBy(j => j.pr.ISIN)
            .Select(g => new { g, MinRank = g.Min(x => x.cas.Rank) })
            .Select(r => r.g.First(x => x.cas.Rank == r.MinRank).pr);
```

Result will be same with both ways:

```
PriceList
ISIN   Source   Price
BN1    ABC      98
MGH    XYZ      102
```

***P.S:*** I have assumed that list's name is as following: `pricesList` and `cascadesList`

Comment: Exactly what OP was looking for! Nice Answer :)

Comment: @RahulSingh Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4):

```
from pr in priceList
join c in cascadeList on pr.Source = c.Source
order by c.Rank
select new {Isin = pr.Isin, Source = pr.Source, Price = pr.Price}
```

Comment: It is amazing, how the obvious wrong (also bad formed) answer can be upwoted.

Comment: I believe this will still return me all 3 BN1 pricedetails but just order or am I missing something?

Comment: @mHelpMe give me a minute

Comment: This will not produce the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you

```
priceList.GroupBy(p => p.ISIN).OrderByDescending(p =>
    cascadeList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Source == p.Source).Rank).First();
```